# Using fixPageXY(e) and onmousemove() and the image wont move?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there something im missing here? I just want to select the image by clicking on it, it should drag with the mouse(no mouse key held down) until its clicked onto I different part of the screen. Ive used function fixPageXY(e) with a onmousemove function, followed a tutorial and still nothing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fixPageXY(e) {
if (e.pageX == null && e.clientX != null ) {
var html = document.documentElement;
var body = document.body;

e.pageX = e.clientX + (html.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0);
e.pageX -= html.clientLeft || 0;

e.pageY = e.clientY + (html.scrollTop || body && body.scrollTop || 0);
e.pageY -= html.clientTop || 0;
 }
}
}


document.getElementById('ball').onmousedown = function() {
   this.style.position = 'absolute';

   var self = this;

   document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    e = e || event;
     fixPageXY(e);
     // put ball center under mouse pointer. 25 is half of width/height
      self.style.left = e.pageX-25+'px';
    self.style.top = e.pageY-25+'px';
   }
    this.onmouseup = function() {
     document.onmousemove = null;
  }
    }
 </script>
```

My image is simply,

```
<body onload="onmousemove();onmouseup();">
 <img id="ball" src="ball.png" style="width:100px;height:100px;"/>
 </body>
```

Im using google chrome, could this be an issue? many thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few syntax errors within your code, which if you are running Chrome you can just hit `F12` on your keyboard and it will bring up the console allowing you to read whatever errors may be there. [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3s51yx0/) with just a few tweaks made to your code that allows it to run smoothly... and by tweaks, I mean there was an extra closing bracket after defining the function and the functions you called in `body` `onload` cannot me accessed that way so I deleted that and it worked.

Comment: Thank you, i have been looking at it for so long those extra brackets i must of passed over them. I also had to wrap my code in         window.onload = function(){   //    my code  };                     to get it to work correctly. Many Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, that works, however the standard nowadays is `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ /* code */ }, false);`, but they both basically do the same thing. Glad to be of service.

Answer (score 0):

This code work fine :

```
function fixPageXY(e) {
    if(e.pageX == null && e.clientX != null ) {
        var html = document.documentElement, body = document.body;
        e.pageX = e.clientX + (html.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0);
        e.pageX -= html.clientLeft || 0;
        e.pageY = e.clientY + (html.scrollTop || body && body.scrollTop || 0);
        e.pageY -= html.clientTop || 0;
    }
}

document.getElementById("ball2").onmousedown = function () {
  this.style.position = "absolute";

  var self = this;

  document.onmousemove = function (e) {
    e = e || event;
    fixPageXY (e); 

    self.style.left = e.pageX-25+'px';
    self.style.top = e.pageY-25+'px';
  }
  this.onmouseup = function () {
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}

document.getElementById("ball2").ondragstart = function () { return false; }
```